# Do multithreading and autorelease pools work together in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

I would like to send an object back to the main thread from worker thread. However do auto-release pools work between threads? Is there anything wrong with the following code:

```
-(void)mainThreadReceiveResult:(id)response
{
  [response retain];
    /* Do some stuff with response */
  [response release];
}


-(void)workerThreadDoWork
{

 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 response * response = [[[response alloc] init] autorelease];
 response->someData = [self getSomeData];

 [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveResult:) withObject:response waitUntilDone:NO];

 [pool release];    

}
```

Seems to work fine. However is it possible that the worker thread could reach `[pool release]` before the main thread is able to retain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code shouldn't crash: `performSelectorOnMainThread:` retains its arguments until after the selector finishes, so your retain/release pair is superfluous.

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:):

> This method retains the receiver and the arg parameter until after the selector is performed.

Also: you should probably `[pool drain]` instead of `[pool release]`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2009/4/28/235516) may answer your question.

Here's what he did to solve the problem. The explanation is given in that link.

```
- (void)runSomethingThatWillFail:(NSError **)error {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/BOGUS" error:error];
   [*error retain];
   [pool release];
   [*error autorelease];
}
```